# Symfony 3: How to valid an array of object?

Tags: symfony, validation

I have the following entity:

```
class Jobs {
//...

  /**
   * Tasks of Jobs
   * @var $tasks array
   */
   protected $tasks;

}
```

`tasks`is stored as Array in Json File like this:

```
[
  {
    "designation": "Task 1",
    "action": "Do action 1",
    //...
  },
  {
    "designation": "Task 2",
    "action": "Do action 2",
    //...
  },
  //...
]
```

When user define data from form, I would like to implement an assert for validation.

I'm implemented this one (I use yml):

```
...\Entity\Jobs:
  properties:
    tasks:
      - Collection:
        allowMissingFields: false
        missingFieldsMessage: jobs.tasks.missingfields
        fields:
          designation:
            - NotBlank:
              message: jobs.tasks.fields.blank
            ##...
```

When I try to validate form, I have a validation error for `data.tasks[designation]` and `data.tasks[action]`.

Validation should be applied on second level of array.
How can I configure the validator for this kind of array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Collection()`-assertion is used when the array key is relevant, as is the case with each array representing a task. If you just care about the values in, e.g. a numerical array, you can use the `@All()`-constraint.

In your case you want to combine both, a list of tasks (`@All`) and each task (`@Collection`) inside that list. As annotation it could look something like this:

```
class Jobs
{
    /**
     * @Assert\All({
     *      @Collection(...)
     * })
     */
    private $tasks;
}
```

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's exactly that.

Comment: What should be the type in the form? nothing?
I mean we are creating the form in the controller, and we have a form for the Jobs class, and we have $builder->add... which has a second parameter we need to set, because this didn't work for me.

Comment: I think you are mixing up form elements with validation constraints. Assuming your Jobs are doctrine entities, then most likely you want an [EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#basic-usage)